# Can I check on my server-side through POST if the divs have some style?

Tags: node.js

Can I check on my server-side through POST if the divs have some style?

I have disabled divs marked with grey color.

I want to check if user doesn't change style of div to bypass its disabled.

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="bii" style="color: blue;">
</form>
```

```
const server = (req, res) => {
    if(req.method === "POST") {
        // check it here
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        fs.readFile("./index.html", (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.write("File not found.");
            } else {
                res.write(data);
            }
            res.end();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You should use javascript and send it to the backend if something changes. There is no other way to see DOM changes from the backend.

Comment: But user can edit his front-end part. He can remove or change javascript, can't he?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: It supposed to be unbreakable by this part.

Comment: Everything on the front-end side breakable, no matters what you have.